# Cannot connect NestJS Bull to Elasticache (Redis)

Tags: redis, queue, nestjs, bull

I stuck when connecting NestJS Bull to AWS Elasticache on deployment

On local I easily connect to Redis by

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        password: 'secret',
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I even try on https://app.redislabs.com/ a official Redis cloud. It still working.

But on deployment with Elasticache. There is no error on startup but the queue is not worked as expected

My code last year was worked, But now no response

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({
      createClient: () => {
        return config.get('redis.cluster.host')
          ? new Redis.Cluster([
              {
                port: +config.get('redis.cluster.port'),
                host: config.get('redis.cluster.host'),
              },
            ])
          : new Redis(+config.get('redis.standalone.port'), config.get('redis.standalone.host'));
      },
    }),
    FeeQueue,
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class QueuesModule {}
```

Could you have time to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it'll be the same for you, but I just ran into a similar issue. The queue wasn't working, but no error logged. After a lot of testing, I finally got it to log an error saying that  `enableReadyCheck` and `maxRetriesPerRequest` can't be used for bclients and subscibers. So I unset them:

```js
BullModule.forRoot({
  createClient: (type) => {
    const opts =
      type !== 'client'
        ? { enableReadyCheck: false, maxRetriesPerRequest: null }
        : {}

    return config.get('redis.cluster.host')
      ? new Redis.Cluster([{ host, port }], opts)
      : new Redis({ host, port, ...opts});
  },
})
```